# Tranform html to data frame using R and rvest in a simple way

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, web-scraping

I have been trying to translate the following html into a data.frame.

```
<pre>      
<a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                    <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <hr>      <a href="/src/contrib/Archive/">Parent Directory</a>                             -      
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz</a>      2019-02-14 22:22  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz</a>      2019-05-14 12:20  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz</a>      2019-06-29 04:50  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz</a>      2019-07-04 15:50  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz</a>      2020-01-31 17:20  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz</a>      2020-03-07 12:20  1.3M  
      <a href="dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz">dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz</a>      2020-05-29 15:00  817K    
<hr></pre>
```

I used `rvest::read_html()` and `read_nodes()`, i wasn't successful!

I need, name, datetime and size

I have tried the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537548/convert-xml-data-to-data-frame-in-r) as well.

Comment: It looks as if you are scraping the package archive for `dplyr`. Why are you trying to get at it that way? There are other ways to download older versions of packages; alternatively, if you're hoping to mirror a CRAN archive directory, there are better (sanctioned/preferred) ways for that, too.

Comment: Also you do have a tag that is incomplete. ie at the very end the tag `<hr>` seems to be missing the forwardslash for it to be the closing tag of `<hr>`

Comment: @r2evans I was not trying to download, I was trying to count how many times a package had an update and few other statistics of r packages. Nothing to do with downloads and installation. Thanks

Comment: @Onyambu, HTML allows such non-closing tags (i.e., `<hr>`, `<br>`) but not XML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As directory listing is between `<pre>` tags (i.e. it's preformatted), we can pass it through `html_text()` and parse with `read.table()` or `read.fwf()` / `readr::read_fwf()`:

```r
library(rvest)
html_str <- 
'<pre>      
<a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                    <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <hr>      <a href="/src/contrib/Archive/">Parent Directory</a>                             -      
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz</a>      2019-02-14 22:22  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz</a>      2019-05-14 12:20  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz</a>      2019-06-29 04:50  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz</a>      2019-07-04 15:50  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz</a>      2020-01-31 17:20  1.1M  
      <a href="dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz">dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz</a>      2020-03-07 12:20  1.3M  
      <a href="dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz">dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz</a>      2020-05-29 15:00  817K    
<hr></pre>'

# parse as preformated text
prefmt <- 
  read_html(html_str) |> 
  html_element("pre") |>
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
stringr::str_view(prefmt)
#> [1] │ Name                    Last modified      Size  Parent Directory                             -      
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz      2019-02-14 22:22  1.1M  
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz      2019-05-14 12:20  1.1M  
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz      2019-06-29 04:50  1.1M  
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz      2019-07-04 15:50  1.1M  
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz      2020-01-31 17:20  1.1M  
#>     │       dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz      2020-03-07 12:20  1.3M  
#>     │       dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz      2020-05-29 15:00  817K

# parse with read.table:
read.table(text = prefmt, skip = 1)
#>                   V1         V2    V3   V4
#> 1 dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz 2019-02-14 22:22 1.1M
#> 2 dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz 2019-05-14 12:20 1.1M
#> 3 dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz 2019-06-29 04:50 1.1M
#> 4 dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz 2019-07-04 15:50 1.1M
#> 5 dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz 2020-01-31 17:20 1.1M
#> 6 dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz 2020-03-07 12:20 1.3M
#> 7 dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz 2020-05-29 15:00 817K
```

With `readr::read_fwf()` and define column widths & names:

```r
readr::read_fwf(prefmt, 
                skip = 1, 
                readr::fwf_widths(widths = c(30, 16, NA), 
                                  col_names = c("Name", "Last modified", "Size")))
#> Rows: 7 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> chr  (2): Name, Size
#> dttm (1): Last modified
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   Name               `Last modified`     Size 
#>   <chr>              <dttm>              <chr>
#> 1 dplyr_0.8.0.tar.gz 2019-02-14 22:22:00 1.1M 
#> 2 dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz 2019-05-14 12:20:00 1.1M 
#> 3 dplyr_0.8.2.tar.gz 2019-06-29 04:50:00 1.1M 
#> 4 dplyr_0.8.3.tar.gz 2019-07-04 15:50:00 1.1M 
#> 5 dplyr_0.8.4.tar.gz 2020-01-31 17:20:00 1.1M 
#> 6 dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz 2020-03-07 12:20:00 1.3M 
#> 7 dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz 2020-05-29 15:00:00 817K
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! ````read_fwf``` did magic!